# How to rig the fingers

Tags: rigging, bones

[`[![enter image description here][1]][1]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHbZG.png)

I was trying to make my finger move at once when I move the lower finger bone(the first one out of three) but things are not working as the tutorials so I'm asking what is wrong with my settings?

The picture above are the settings of my two finger bones that has a copy rotation restriction for each. And I made them they're able to rotate in the X axis only. Is there anything wrong with this?

Or is there an another way of making my finger move at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your space is set to world instead of local for your "copy rotation" constraint. I would also recommend changing the bone roll of the fingers bones to bend along the x axis.

Then tweak the amount of influence for the bones with the constraints applied.

[image: copy rotation]
[image]
[image: finger]